# slow response IExplorer opening new item or editing a list item

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-foundation, content-editor-web-part, internet-explorer

I have a Sharepoint 2013 Foundation running on a Windows server 2012 R2. It's a domain controller as well. Yes I know its not a best practice but the company has limited funds. And does not want to go in the Cloud.

SP2013 is running fine but its incredibly slow in IExplorer when opening a list item in edit mode. In Chrome or Firefox the response time opening a list item in edit mode is fine. Also when creating new item in the list.

Until now I cannot find the reason for this slow response in IExplorer. In Chrome the response is fine but it does not have a rich text editor ribbon in the description field. It only displays in IExplorer. 
I looked already to replace the standard Rich Text Editor from Sharepoint for an alternative RTE. THere are some RTE's for SP2010 (TinyMCE or CKeditor) but because the template for the list items' edit field in SharePoint 2013 is implemented entirely on the client I am not sure it will work. Couldn't find any sites or examples for SP2013 either unfortunately. 
Also I am a novice to Sharepoint and java/css/jquery. So I am at a loss...

Does anyone have a solution to the slow response in IExplorer or
does anyone know how to implement a good RTE in Chrome or firefox.

already tried resetting ie back to defaults and started ie excluding addons/plugins (iexplorer.exe -extoff)
no dice...

with F12 i can see that it hangs on a script that IE is waiting for. But cannot figure out what script that is.

getting error: apphangxprocb1

but googling shows me it can be anything.

http://static.spiceworks.com/shared/post/0003/9630/sp2013error.jpg

Comment: which version of the IE are you running? and do you open SP in IE in compatibility mode? Have you tried to collect Fiddler traces it may point which script is slow.

Comment: Another tool that may help you is the SP Developer Dashboard it may point which calls are slow. It is build it you just need to enable it using PowerShell.